# 1800MB/s sequential R/W on a SATA 3 SSD?

Tags: ssd, sata

I ran CrystalDiskMark on my SATA 3 connected Samsung Evo 850 SSD, and it reported a 1839MB/s sequential read speed, and 1676MB/s write speed. SATA 3 has a maximum of 750MB/s and Samsung says at best it would perform at 540MB/s. Is the software wrong, why is it so fast?[image]

Comment: Something is not right there. I am curious if the Seq is supposed to be in bits not Bytes. Still, at that you would be in the 200s

Comment: @Tim I would also be curious if any ram caching is being measured if it is not bits / bytes translation.

Comment: It is best to use a Samsung SSD tool to determine the performance of a Samsung SSD.  I honestly wouldn't trust CDM.

Comment: @iancnorden ram does seem more likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently some of the Samsung SSD use a technology called RAPID mode. As far as I can tell this is basically a huge cache using the PC's memory. The effect you see from this in benchmarking is a dominance of memory transfer speed over SATA transfer speed especially on sequential (and therefor predictable) operations.

References:

- http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2257380/samsung-evo-250gb-high-incorrect-benchmark-results.html
- http://techreport.com/review/25282/a-closer-look-at-rapid-dram-caching-on-the-samsung-840-evo-ssd

Comment: The Samsung Magician benchmark had similar results. I also checked the RAM usage as the benchmark was running, and it increased at the same time as I started the benchmark, confirming what you said.